# What is the mass of an E.coli cell?

Tags: cell-biology, ecoli

I'm trying to get into Biology, reading introductory texts. A discussion on *E.Coli* estimates the mass of the cell from $$density =1g/mL=1g/cm^3$$ and $$volume=1µm^3$$ From this I get $$ mass=density × volume = \frac {10^{-6} g}{10^{-2}}=10^{-4} g$$ which is wrong since the answer is supposed to be $1pg$. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its simple:

```
Mass = Density * Volume

= 10^3 (Kg/m3) * (10^-18 m3)

= 10^-15 Kg
```

which is equal to `10^-12` gram or 1pico gram

Comment: Wiki gives me micrometers to be $10^{-6}m$. And also that an $mL=cm^3$. Since I don't come from a background where units were ever used, can u please elaborate on how u got ur density and volume compared to mine? Thanks

Comment: @Craig Yes micrometers are indeed `10^-6` meters. But `1 micrometer^3` = `(10^-6)^3` = `10^-18`

Comment: `10^-18` is in `m3`

Comment: Ahh... I should've paid attention in high school  physics